# Two-Way Data Binding using jQuery Driven "Chosen" Drop Down

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen

Alright, I have a jQuery version of Chosen applied to a `select` displaying properly on my page and I've done so with the following code. First I have a `BaseController` that sets a `ViewBag` property listing all of the possible categories:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    try
    {
        _connection.Open();
        this.ViewBag.AvailableCategories = new MultiSelectList(_connection.Query<Category>("select * from Category"), "CategoryID", "Name");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Next, when navigating to `/Event/View/1` I have the `EventController` setup (**NOTE** this controller bases the aforementioned controller) with the following `View` method.

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    Event evt = null;

    try
    {
        evt = Event.Where(_connection, id);
        if (evt == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Oops! The event you're looking for does not exist.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
    }

    return View(evt);
}
```

It sets the model, as you can see, to the following model.

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public int BusinessID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int NeighborhoodID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> CategoryIds
    {
        get
        {
            if (Categories == null) { return new List<int>(); }
            return Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryID).AsEnumerable();
        }
    }

    public List<EventCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<EventHours> Hours { get; set; }

    public static Event Where(IDbConnection connection, int id)
    {
        Event result = null;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            var sql =
                @"  select * from Event where EventID = @EventID
                    select * from EventCategory where EventID = @EventID
                    select * from EventHours where EventID = @EventID";
            using (var multiResult = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new { EventID = id }))
            {
                result = multiResult.Read<Event>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    result.Categories = multiResult.Read<EventCategory>().ToList();
                    result.Hours = multiResult.Read<EventHours>().ToList();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Finally I have the following markup in the view.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryIds,
    ViewBag.AvailableCategories as MultiSelectList,
    new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "chzn-container" })
```

Now, as I stated at first, it's displaying properly and listing all of the categories as expected. However, even though the `CategoryIds` property does list in fact two selected categories, it's not setting them (or showing them for that matter) as selected in the Chosen drop down on load.

I am forced to only further assume that if a user selected a value from the Chosen drop down that it would not bind properly on post either because it does not change the HTML when an item is selected.

So, my question is this, how do I properly two-way data bind to a Chosen drop down in MVC?

Comment: Can you look at the generated html and see if the select list has values?

Comment: @kabaros, yeah both the SELECT and the generated HTML have items. So, did I misunderstand you in that are you speaking of the value attribute?

Comment: yes I am speaking about the value attribute in the Select>Option

Comment: @kabaros, they did all have values.

Comment: What exactlay is your problem? Mutliselect is properly diplayed on the page but not transmitted back when POSTing back users selection?

Comment: @Lukas, The `select` appears to get built properly, but nothing is actually `selected` even though the list of `CategoryIds` has matching values.

Comment: @Lukas: please note this statement in the question `However, even though the CategoryIds property does list in fact two selected categories, it's not setting them (or showing them for that matter) as selected in the Chosen drop down on load.` -- I think next time I'll pull it out on another line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListBoxFor` is the helper you should use for multiselect lists

replacing

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryIds,
    ViewBag.AvailableCategories as MultiSelectList,
    new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "chzn-container" })
```

with

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CategoryIds,
    ViewBag.AvailableCategories as MultiSelectList,
    new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "chzn-container" })
```

should do the trick